# Return Number of Sub Folders C#

Tags: c#

I have a very basic WinForms App that searches for the number of files in a specified folder that the user selects. The code is:

```
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (checkSubFolders.Checked = !true)
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                txbNumberOfFiles.Text = files.Length.ToString();
                txbFilePath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }
```

Now what I want to do is also return the number of files in sub-folders when my check box is checked. Is there a simplistic way to do this? Thanks

Comment: You might want to fix that `if (checkSubFolders.Checked = !true)`. Right now it's actually assigning false to the `Checked` property. You probably mean `if (checkSubFolders.Checked)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am under the impression that you will always get the files?

If so then you can drop the if statement for that part.

```
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            txbNumberOfFiles.Text = files.Length.ToString();
            txbFilePath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

            if(checkSubFolders.Checked)
            {
                 //You can do the same as before here with Directory.GetFiles();
                 Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
                 //Gets the number of files in subfolders and so on. Ofcourse you would have to parametrise path.

            }
    }
```

If you don't want to drop the if statement then you can do If/Else, but you will be duplicating code, so at the very least I would put this part:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        txbNumberOfFiles.Text = files.Length.ToString();
        txbFilePath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

Into it's own method, then call that method in the if/else

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("PATH");`

var subDirs = di.GetDirectories;

Then count / on the returned array.. that should do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to search recursively:

```
SearchOption searchOption = checkSubFolders.Checked ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*", searchOption);
txbNumberOfFiles.Text = files.Length.ToString();
txbFilePath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this

```
SearchOption option = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
if (checkSubFolders.Checked)
    option = SearchOption.AllDirectories;

int totalFiles  = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", option).Length;
```